# How to listen DataContext change to adjust UI state accordingly

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

This question is taking roots from discussion inside https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/367 thread.

If we're following the recent examples of setting up Bindings with MvvmCross framework then we just setup bindings to control properties (like UILabel.Text) using Bind(), To() extensions:

```cs
this.DelayBind(() => {
    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<KittenCollectionCell, Kitten>();
    set.Bind(NameLabel).To(kitten => kitten.Name);
    set.Bind(PriceLabel).To(kitten => kitten.Price);
    set.Bind(_loader).To(kitten => kitten.ImageUrl);
    set.Apply();
});
```

(taken from https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-11-KittenView_Collections/KittenView.Touch/Views/KittenCollectionCell.cs)

But what if I want to adjust my UI state basing on some values from DataContext. For example I would like to show/hide some buttons and labels and to adjust some constraint values.

```cs
if (((UserInfo)DataContext).IsAdmin)
{
    SaveButton.Hidden = false;
    SecurityLabelConstraint.Constant = 50;

    /* etc */
}
```

How I can listen DataContext change event? What's the recommended approach here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several way to achieve this.

One of the simplest is the way you've already identified yourself - e.g. to bind the SecurityLabelConstraint directly - e.g. using `Tibet` binding:

```
set.Bind(SecurityLabelConstraint)
   .For(p => p.Constant)
   .To("If(info.IsAdmin, 20, 0)");
```

Alternatively if there is complicated logic needed (beyond the scope or performance of the Tibet binding engine) then you can implement the binding to a property on your cell - or on to an intermediate object.

For example, you could have a Wrapper class which implements:

```
 public class Wrapper
 {
     private NSLayoutConstraint _constraint;
     public Wrapper(NSLayoutConstraint constraint)
     {
         _constraint = constraint;
     }

     private string _foo;
     public string Foo
     {
        get { return _foo; }
        set
        {
           _foo = value;
           // your complex logic on _constraint goes here
        }
     }
 }
```

If you store a `_wrapper` instance in a field on the cell, then this can be bound as:

```
set.Bind(_wrapper)
   .For(p => p.Foo)
   .To(info => info.IsAdmin);
```

If you had instead put the Foo property on the cell, then you could have used:

```
set.Bind()
   .For(cell => cell.Foo)
   .To(info => info.IsAdmin);
```

One final way to achieve the binding is to try to hook into the cell's `DataContext` directly and to use the `PropertyChanged` handler - I don't recommend this as it tends to get a bit fiddly to maintain and as it's easy to create memory leaks when accessing NSObject's inside event callbacks.

Comment: Overriding DataContext setter would work for ancestors of MvxTableViewCell base class, because it's defined there as virtual, but if you work with MvxViewController you can't override it, but just replace it (so you won't get data context instance anyway). Maybe it's an API improvement issue for MvvmCross framework.

Answer (score 0):

So far I decided to bind each of controls or constraints to an appropriate property of a DataContext, like:

```
this.DelayBind(() => {
    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<UserCell, UserInfo>();

    set.Bind(SecurityLabelConstraint).For(p => p.Constant).To(info => info.IsAdmin)
        .WithConversion(new ValueConverter<string>(s => s != null ? 20 : 0), null);

    // etc...

    set.Apply();
});
```

It works pretty well.